# Visual Basic: I'm trying to roll two dice

Tags: vb.net, random

In Visual Basic, I'm trying to roll two dice.  I'm always getting die1 and die2 being the same random Integer from 1 to 6.  Why aren't die1 and die2 each random and showing as different random values???  In the RollD6() function, n is of local scope within RollD6(), right?

```
Public Class frmCrapsWin
    Dim pot As Decimal = 0D
    Dim point, result As Integer
    Dim wager As Decimal = 0D
    Dim points(99) As Integer
    Dim wagerCoefficient(99) As Decimal

    Function RollD6() As Integer
        Dim randomNum As New Random
        Dim n As Integer
        n = randomNum.Next(1, 7)  ' random number (1,6)
        Return n
    End Function

    Private Sub btnRoll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoll.Click
        Dim die1 As Integer
        Dim die2 As Integer
        die1 = RollD6()
        die2 = RollD6()
        lstOutput.Items.Add("die 1: " & die1 & "    die 2: " & die2 & "     Result: " & (die1 + die2))
        lstOutput.Items.Add("die 1: " & die1)
        lstOutput.Items.Add("die 2: " & die2)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The rule for successful random numbers is only one instance of `Random` per thread. Try this: `<ThreadStatic()> Private randomNum As New Random`.

Comment: I solved the problem by using the Rnd() function:

```
Function RollD6() As UInteger
        RollD6 = (Math.Floor(6 * Rnd())) + 1
        Return RollD6
End Function
```

When the form loads, I use the Randomize() method to make sure I don't always get the same sequence of random numbers from run to run.

Comment: That's a bad RNG. You should use `Random` at least.